# Froala Editor CSS not applying angular 5

Tags: angular, froala

I am new with [Froala Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and trying to integrate it in my Angular 5 Project but after integration styles and css not applying on `Froala Editor`. Following guide from [here](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg#use-with-angular-cli)

I have tried as follow.

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"
            ],
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
//..Other Imports 

import "froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js";
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(), 
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div [froalaEditor]>Hello, Froala!</div>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Description**

Don't know why it's result is weird. If have any idea then please share with us.

Comment: check your angular.json path

Comment: Yes I tried with that in angular.json file like ../node_module or only node_module

Comment: change to ./node_module

Comment: ok let me try...

Comment: Not working I have tried it before a moment

Comment: Any js error in the console?

Comment: No there is no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally  I found the answer and I did silly mistake, But I want to answer my own question in detail so it will helps other.

**Installing @angular/cli**

**Note:** you can skip this part if you already have application generated.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
cd my-app
```

**Add angular-froala-wysiwyg**

```
npm install angular-froala-wysiwyg --save   

open src/app/app.module.ts and add

// Import Angular plugin. 
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(), FroalaViewModule.forRoot() ... ],
   ...
})
```

> open **angular.json** file and insert a new entry into the **styles array**

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
  "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]
```

> in **angular.json** file insert a new entry into the **scripts array**

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"
]
```

> open src/app/app.component.html and add

```
<div [froalaEditor]>Hello, Froala!</div>
```

**Note :**

Make sure you are adding **styles** and **scrips** in **build** portion as below. Because I did the same mistake and I asked question here. So Please you don't do that.

```
"build": {
          //..other code
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
              "./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"
            ]
          },
          //..other Code
        },
```

Comment: How is this any different than what you initially tried?
Looks like youv'e added those at the first comment as well.
Im asking as Im having the same issue, froala css classes aren't applying, and Iv'e added it to the styles array in my angular.json /:

Comment: Check you are adding in a "build" Portion as I have mention in Answer Note: Part.

Comment: Its inside build inside options.
can't have it outside of options. yet I still can't see froala css classes... any idea mate? ty

Comment: Seems like my issue was that I need to add class - .fr-view
on wherever I wanted to use froala classes. guess I'll just inject it to the top of the page or something.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and the solution was even more basic: 
Remember to restart your dev-server. Changes on `angular.json` are not detected automatically and manual restart is necessary.